# SQL Server CE. Delete data from all tables for integration tests

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, integration-testing

We are using SQL Server CE for our integration tests. At the moment before every test, we delete all data from all columns, then re-seed test data. And we drop the database file when the structure changes.

For deletion of data we need to go through every table in correct order and issue `Delete from table blah` and that is error-prone. Many times I simply forget to add delete statement when I add new entities. So it would be good if we can automate data-deletion from the tables.

I have seen Jimmy Bogard's  goodness for [deletion of data in the correct order](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/18/isolating-database-data-in-integration-tests/). I have implemented that for Entity Frameworks and that works in full-blown SQL Server. But when I try to use that in SQL CE for testing, I get exception, saying

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : The specified table does not exist. [ @@sys.tables ]
```

SQL CE does not have supporting system tables that hold required information.

Is there a script that works with SQL CE version that can delete all data from all tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact does in fact have system tables listing all tables. In my SQL Server Compact scripting API, I have code to list the tables in the "correct" order, not a trivial task! I use QuickGraph, it has an extension method for sorting a DataSet. You should be able to reuse some of that in your test code:
33

```
public void SortTables()
{
    var _tableNames = _repository.GetAllTableNames();
    try
    {
        var sortedTables = new List<string>();
        var g = FillSchemaDataSet(_tableNames).ToGraph();
        foreach (var table in g.TopologicalSort())
        {
            sortedTables.Add(table.TableName);
        }
        _tableNames = sortedTables;
        //Now iterate _tableNames and issue DELETE statement for each
    }
    catch (QuickGraph.NonAcyclicGraphException)
    {
        _sbScript.AppendLine("-- Warning - circular reference preventing proper sorting of tables");
    }
}
```

You must add the QuickGraph DLL files (from Codeplex or NuGet) and you can find the implementation of GetAllTableNames and FillSchemaDataSet here http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets (in Generator.cs and DbRepository.cs)

Comment: oh, wow! that looks very interesting. I have seen your project when was looking for the answer, but did not pay more attention. I'll surely have a go on that!